# Help debugging "An unknown error occurred."

Tags: error

Recently, when I edit categories or entries I get the dreaded "An unknown error occurred." When I check the logs I see:

```
2017/12/11 20:41:51 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.403] Craft\HttpException in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/0default/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php:329
```

Not quite sure where to go from there. 403 makes it look like a permissions issue but my permissions are all setup just like I normally have them (744). Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/services/UserSessionService.php#L325

The error is thrown when you don't have the permission to change/do something. Your file permissions do not matter it is about the permissions in craft. Are you not admin? Could you tell us if you are a normal user and don't have certain permissions? Maybe another member of your team changed something?

Do you have any plugins installed that have any hooks/events? 
Do you have the latest Craft version?

Comment: Thanks Robin. I'm the only admin and I only have a handful of plugins, with only Hill Holliday's "Documentation" plugin going anywhere near permissions. Feel like it might be an environment issue of sorts, since my local copy (on MAMP) is just fine.